# How to theme up KDE?

Tags: 12.04, themes, kde

I just installed KDE and I like it very much and have themed it up a bit.
[image: My laptop]

Like all that lightblue design, but how do I change the theme for GNOME applications like nautilus or marlin? and also how do I change the gray color of kmess and Chromium and many other apps?

I installed kde with this command

```
sudo apt-get install kde-full
```

Comment: Are you trying to make GNOME Applications Look Like KDE Applications?

Comment: i think so.. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oxygen widget theme for GTK+/GTK3-based applications**

The Kubuntu /1/ is using the gtk2-engines-oxygen /2/ and the gtk3-engines-oxygen /3/ as part of the desktop.

If you don't want to use the Kubuntu desktop you could install the gtk2/gtk3 engines.

**Installing KDE**

By the Ubuntu community wiki - Installing KDE /4/:

> If you choose to not install kubuntu-desktop, then you can still get
>   all the Kubuntu-specific tweaks by installing the
>   kubuntu-default-settings package.

**More**

Other options:

- kde-gtk-config: https://launchpad.net/kde-gtk-config

PPA package search: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas
 => A PPA: https://launchpad.net/~hrvojes/+archive/kde-goodies

**Links**

1. http://www.kubuntu.org/
2. http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gtk2-engines-oxygen
3. http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gtk3-engines-oxygen
4. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE

Comment: I just installed them all, kde-full, kubuntu-desktop, kde-plasma-desktop and now it have the same gray color as all others apps. How can i change the color?

Answer (score 0):

In-order to change the theme for gnome applications, see [How To Make GNOME Applications Look Like KDE Applications With Oxygen-GTK [Linux]](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/gnome-applications-kde-applications-oxygengtk-linux/).

Use this if you like to use KDE but still keep the GNOME applications.

That is, install the `oxygen-gtk` package. Then, as the linked page says:

> go into your Desktop/System Settings, then Application Appearance, and finally GTK+ Style. Here you need to change the widget style to oxygen-gtk. Hit Apply, and now you can open any GNOME application and see that it visually fits right along all your other applications!

Comment: I tried to follow that "how to" but im stuck at installing 'oxygen-gtk' I don't have KPackageKit. and don't know how to get it.

Comment: You can install it using **Synaptic Package Manager**